# How to iterate over range between two datetime objects in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

Let's assume we have two dataetime objects as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object1 = datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2020  9:40PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
datetime_object2 = datetime.strptime('Jan 2 2020  3:40AM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
```

What I am trying to do is to somehow loop over these two dates ranges in x minutes steps. For example below I want to print every 5 mins between these two objects:

```
for t in range(datetime_object1, datetime_object2, 5):
    print(t)
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use the code in the duplicate with `timedelta(minutes=5)`